# SQL Query to get differences between the values from two rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm looking for an SQL-Query to calculate the difference between two values like in the following example:

```
Date        |  OrderNr |   TotalDelivered | ->   DeliveredToday
01.08.2016  |  123     |   1000           | ->   1000
01.08.2016  |  456     |   250            | ->   250
01.08.2016  |  789     |   3400           | ->   3400
02.08.2016  |  123     |   1300           | ->   300
02.08.2016  |  456     |   400            | ->   150
02.08.2016  |  789     |   4000           | ->   600
05.08.2016  |  123     |   1300           | ->   0
05.08.2016  |  456     |   500            | ->   100
05.08.2016  |  789     |   4050           | ->   50
```

So the query should automatically calculate the "DeliveredToday" value for each OrderNr and every day.

Is this possible?

Thanks for your help

Comment: What is the logic behind this?

Comment: Yes, what is the logic and also can you post the query that you have tried to write?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`LAG` function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions070.htm) to access the previous row of the same order and then calculate the difference:

```
SELECT t.Date, 
    t.OrderNr, 
    t.TotalDelivered,
    t.TotalDelivered - t.PreviousDelivered as DeliveredToday
FROM
    (SELECT 
        Date, 
        OrderNr, 
        TotalDelivered,
        LAG(TotalDelivered, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY OrderNr ORDER BY Date ASC) AS PreviousDelivered
    FROM tableName
    ) t
```

Here in subquery I used function `LAG` to get the previous value of `TotalDelivered` for the same order (this is specified by `PARTITION BY OrderNr`) and ordered by date (`ORDER BY Date ASC`). Then in outer query I subtract value of `PreviousDelivered` from `TotalDelivered` and the result is number of delivered today.

**Edit:** As @SandipPatel mentioned in comments, it is possible not to use subquery:

```
SELECT 
        Date, 
        OrderNr, 
        TotalDelivered,
        TotalDelivered-LAG(TotalDelivered, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY OrderNr ORDER BY Date ASC) AS PreviousDelivered
FROM tableName
```

Comment: Good one, you can direct use subquery statement without upper select query

Comment: @SandipPatel Yes, you could write everything without the subquery, but I thought the code would be more understandable with subquery

Comment: can i know from where i can find this type of function like (lag), i am not able to find in my sql server default system function

Comment: @SandipPatel `LAG` was introduced in SQL Server 2012 (as you can see in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx), so if you are using earlier version of SQL Server you will not find it